# How could there be multiple instances of Moody in Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire?

Tags: harry-potter

I understand that Barty Crouch Jr. had drank a potion called Polyjuice to transform into a likness of Moody whilst keeping the real Moody locked up. However, there appears to be a discrepancy.

When Harry Potter was walking back to his room following the discovery of what the golden egg contained, he saw Crouch sneaking in Professor Snape's office and thought it was Barty Crouch, *Sr.*, as was later revealed.

So, if the potion had worn off and Crouch Jr. was in the office, and Moody later showed up at that same time, is it safe to say that there was some inconsistency in the narration, or was he simply a fast runner and was able to go about silently without being noticed from Snape's office to the foot of the staircase?

Comment: There's no indication that the potion had worn off.  Crouch-Moody was there for potion ingredients, presumably ahead of the potion wearing off, and the Marauder's Map saw through the polyjuice potion.

Comment: is there any instance shown of Harry seeing Moody's name on the map? I can't recall and don't have the text in front of me

Comment: It's not clear from your question what problem you actually think exists.

Comment: @jwodder Exactly, as brewing the potion take about a month, he must get the ingredients well in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that Barty Crouch Jr., having spent months impersonating another individual, had gotten pretty good at being sneaky and quick.  He slipped into Snape's office (and may or may not, on that visit, have stolen some boomslang skin or other ingredients), then darted somewhere else, to be seen in disguise as Moody.

He was never out of his disguise.  He made sure he was regularly dosing himself with the Polyjuice potion and keeping enough of it constantly brewing.  The Marauders' Map showed his actual name, despite the disguise, but he never dropped Moody's shape.

Comment: The map is pretty powerful - it sees through polyjuice and animagus transformations.

Answer (score 5):

Based upon the revelation that Moody was actually Barty Crouch Jr. at the end of the book, it can be implied that the Marauder's Map can see through Polyjuice Potion or any other means of concealment (probably another reason why Moody wanted to "borrow" the map from Harry).

It didn't matter whether Crouch Jr. was taking Polyjuice Potion or not, if Harry had looked at the map while standing in front of Moody then he would've seen the name "Barty Crouch" right in front of his own name.